# Intellij IDEA 14.0.3 builds all Android variants

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

When running an Android project in Intelli IDEA 14.0.3, it always builds all build variants. Not only is this slow but if you have an interactive setup on release builds (such as a popup or console read), the build always requires that interaction. This is simply impractical.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this ? It's the only thing stopping us for migrating from 14.0.2 (which has it's own issues with recent gradle versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135783) which will hopefully be fixed in 14.0.4.